# Kotlin - initial an array for custom class object

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I am a beginner of Kotlin. I would like to initial an empty custom class array. Most Kotlin tutorials focus on primitive types Array, but not custom class Array.

I have tried the following, but it failed to work.

```
class MyAudioPlayer {

    // Error
    // Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but AudioItem was expected.    
    var items: Array<AudioItem> = Array<AudioItem>(0) {}

    ......
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: try `arrayOf()` instad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`Array` constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html) you're using takes a size and a lambda that creates an element for each index, for example you could use it like this (pretending that `AudioItem` takes an `Int` parameter):

```
var items: Array<AudioItem> = Array<AudioItem>(0) { index -> AudioItem(index) }
```

But to create an empty `Array`, you can just use [`arrayOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of.html):

```
var items: Array<AudioItem> = arrayOf()
```

Or simply [`emptyArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/empty-array.html):

```
var items: Array<AudioItem> = emptyArray()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to initialize by different known objects

```
        var myData = arrayOf(
           AudioItem("Tartak", "Song 1", 3.52),
           AudioItem("Topolsky", "Song 2", 5.7)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way with an initial size of 0 is with `emptyArray`:

```
var items = emptyArray<AudioItem>()
```